# PHP SOAP Request via SOAPClient to SAP - params missing error

Tags: php, soap, sap-erp

I am doing a PHP SOAP Request as follows (my code, location removed as I'm not allow to publish)

```
try {
    $location = "http://myUrltoWSDLhere";

    $client = new SoapClient($location, 
            array(
                'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
                'login'   => 'myuser',
                'password'   => 'mypass'
                ));

    $params = array(array('BUKRS'=> 1));

    $x = $client->ZIbFtiWsCredPosToWeb( $params );

    print_r($x);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I've been trying countless combinations how to pass the params to my method and I am doing a print_r($x) and gives me the below output.

**stdClass Object ( [EBkpf] => stdClass Object ( ) [EMsgnr] => 6 [EMsgtxt] => BUKRS is missing [EMsgtyp] => E [ESstMon] => 00000000000000000000 )**

Important: SoapClient getTypes returns the following for this method and the IBukrs is the field I am trying to pass data to. In SAP the Company Code is "BUKRS" so I had tried BUKRS and IBukrs and also Bukrs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
    [43] => struct ZIbFtiWsCredPosToWeb {
 int IAnz;
 char1 IAp;
 char4 IBukrs;
 ZibSstGjahr IGjahr;
 ZibSstCredTt IKreditor;
 char1 IOp;
 numeric20 ISstMon;
}
```

WSDL Content: http://pastebin.com/fU5PhD9B

Comment: Yes I tried that, also tried using new StdClass since it's a struct.. I add wsdl content in 1min

Comment: WSDL Here: http://pastebin.com/fU5PhD9B

Comment: You said you tried with StdClass, but I'll give a shot.. I'd try something like `$t = new StdClass();$t->IBukrs = "abcd";$params = array($t);`

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: Just for closure, I was doing everything good (using arrays was enough) the issue was from the soap server and poor documentation. Now solved! Thanks anyway for your help!!